# Firebase throws “auth/network-request-failed” on signInAnonymously() while running jest tests

Tags: javascript, authentication, firebase, jestjs

I'm writing some tests for my app (is build with create-react-app) using firebase and I'm trying to anonymously login into my test database. But authentication fails. However all other firebase operations (CRUD) work just fine.

I can also login anonymously from my application that runs in a browser.

The code is very simple:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
firebase
    .auth()
    .signInAnonymously()
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Gives me back this:

```
O {
  code: 'auth/network-request-failed',
  message: 'A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.'
}
```

But I actually see users that appear in the Firebase console:
[image]

Anonymous access is enabled:
[image]

And here are my access rules. But it never comes to the point of dealing with rules since I can't login.

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$user_id": {
        ".read": "$user_id === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So what's going on? Are there any special things I need to do to make it work in command line? Or should I switch anything in the firebase console?

Maybe any hint on how can I debug it deeper?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same thing given that code sample. I'm using firebase version 4.2.0.

Comment: Any luck? I have stumbled across the same issue.

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Comment: This most likely has something to do with jest and its permissions/maybe the time it waits to run tests