# Firebase 'A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.'

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, jestjs

I'm trying to write some tests for my database client which requires me to first authenticate into Firebase.

I'm using Jest as my test runner.

My test looks like:

```
it ('should sign in ', async (done) => {
  try {
    await auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword('testabc@test.com', 'testuser');
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
  done();
});
```

My firebase app has been initialized and I have validated that the API key is correct.

A couple of interesting notes are that even though I get:

```
'A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.'
```

On the firebase console, I see that my test user has signed in. Mirroring: [Firebase throws “auth/network-request-failed” on signInAnonymously() while running jest tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45390380/firebase-throws-auth-network-request-failed-on-signinanonymously-while-runni)

It doesn't seem like an authentication issue (wrong password/wrong email) as I get the same error for attempting to login as a user that does not exist.

Sign in via launching my app through the browser and inputting credentials into input fields works with no issues.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does [this github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/73) solve the problem?

Comment: No luck. I did forget to note that my sign in via browser works fine though.

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar results when there was Proxy and/or certificate issues blocking things.

What I would do is first enable logging: `firebase.database.enableLogging(true);`

Then take a look at what it says. If you can't see what is blocking I'd then run [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), we were able to see what was happening then.

Answer (score 1):

This problem occurs when there is no active internet connection in your mobile.
I received the same error because I forgot to enable my network connection in my device. First check your Android manifest file to make sure you have granted network permissions. In my case it was done. So I used my emulator then it started working fine. (For more thorough diagnasis you can use if clause to check whether internet connection is active or not)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it worked when I changed

```
auth.useEmulator('http://localhost:9099')
```

to

```
auth.useEmulator('http://127.0.0.1:9099')
```

in my jest tests.

Answer (score 0):

1- Reason is Simple ! Check if Device has internet connection.
2- if you have google services enabled

Answer (score 0):

In my case It happened using the Android Emulator.
Closing and restarting the Emulator solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had also the same problem, Just restart your IDE and emulator and make sure that have connected wifi. Then open again and run your app.

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers. *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*

Comment: @EricAya oH sorry, I didn't see that this is already answered. I just read the question. But thanks for mentioning it.